# Valid or Invalid HTML5?

Tags: html, html-lists

Can you guys please tell me that the following code is valid or invalid ? can i use div tag inside list?

```
<ul>
  <li> <a href="#"> Sample </a>
<ul>
<li> Main </li>
<div>
  <p> <a href="Sample"> </a> </p>
</div>
</ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not valid because `<div>` tag is not allowed inside a `<ul>` element, you'll need to add it inside a `<li>` tag to make it valid:

```
<li> Main </li>
<li><div><p> <a href="Sample"> </a> </p></div></li>
```

**I recommend you to use http://validator.w3.org/check instead of asking here in SO.**